# Хранение аффилированных лиц в бд

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В БД есть таблица company_card

**company_card**

```
 id  company_name
  143 Компния 1
  144 Компния 2
  145 Компния 3
```

Несколько компаний могут быть связаны между собой(аффилированны), компании могут добавляться и удаляться из связи

До определенного момента было достаточно хранить связь в столбце ref_company, т.к. требовалось только отображение, сейчас могут поступать запросы и выискивать регулярным выражением не лучший вариант.

**company_card**

```
id  company_name ref_company_ids
143 Компния 1    144,145
144 Компния 2    143,145
145 Компния 3    143,144
```

Как лучше организовать хранение? Выделить отдельную таблицу ref_company_group? Но кроме как столбца id она должна что-то хранить, если нет есть ли смысл ее делать?

**ref_company_group**

```
id
```

**company_card**

```
id  company_name ref_company_group_id
143 Компния 1    1
144 Компния 2    1
145 Компния 3    1
```

Comment: обычная связь многие-ко-многим, столь же обычное решение — хранить таблицу связей **references** `(company_id, compony_ref_id)`, по желанию можно сдобрить суррогатным ключом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer *обычная связь многие-ко-многим* В конкретной описанной предметной области это может быть и не так - тут "вассал моего вассала не мой вассал" работает не всегда. И, например, не факт, что при выпадении промежуточной аффилированной компании из цепочки сама цепочка рассыплется.

Comment: @Fat-Zer. Нет главной компании в цепочке,чтобы к ней делать запрос. Каждая может быть удалена.
По предложенной структуре получится. что на 3 компании добавлять 6 строк

Comment: @Сергей, тогда, подразумевая, что компания может быть членом только одной группы аффилирования, можно как и описано... при этом заводить отдельную таблицу `ref_company_group` не обязательно... ну и как сказал Akina, предметная область может отличаться от того, что я себе представляю...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Уточняю, "как и описано" - это значит группировка? Без создания отдельной таблицы, я там понимаю нужно самим уникальный ключ на серверной стороне генерировать и записывать в столбец ref_company_group_id?

Comment: >>это значит группировка?<< — да, то что описано в вопросе, если всё как я понимаю и аффилирование устраивает отношение эквивалентности между компаниями... про генерацию значений, честно, не подумал... отдельная таблица — неплохой вариа... но можно просто по умолчанию присваивать id_группы=id_компании. Единственное, будет не тривиально удалять компанию из своей собственной группы...